# React Js : no such file or directory, open Package.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, package.json

While running npm start , I am getting error -

PS D:\React\operations_app_tut> npm start

```
npm ERR! path D:\React\operations_app_tut\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\React\operations_app_tut\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\IT-DI\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-16T05_56_02_304Z-debug.log
```

**While checking physical path made sure file exists -**

[image]

**Structure Of Project For Ref -**

[image]

I referred few sites and again ran -npm install
But same error persisted.

Comment: try running `npm start` from within ` D:\React\operations_app_tut\operations_app_tut`

Comment: Thanks @Adithya I already had on - D:\React\operations_app_tut> npm start   (Ref - Line 2 of question)

Comment: did you try the same in vs code terminal?

Comment: you have 2 folders named the same, `package.json` is within inner `operations_app_tut`. run any anp commands within that folder. or use `--prefix` to specify project location`, like `npm --prefix /path/to/project run build`

Comment: @Adithya Got you. My mistake was , I was not making command calls through inner folders. Now my error is resolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are running `npm start` in incorrect folder.Also why there is package-lock.json outside.

move to `D:\React\operations_app_tut\operations_app_tut` directory
then run `npm start`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @NitinDev And @Adithya.

**Adding details if future contributor faces the same issue -**

My mistake here was , I had a folder `D:/React`
Within this folder I had all my react projects.
I manually created - `operations_app_tut` folder in `D:/React`

After this I opened it through Visual Code via path :- `D:/React/operations_app_tut` and ran command -

```
npx create-react-app operations_app_tut
```

This command created another folder within `operations_app_tut` which made my project path to be - `D:/React/operations_app_tut/operations_app_tut`

Since I was running npm start on terminal with path - `D:/React/operations_app_tut` which was not the actual path , it was giving me error.

**Lesson -**

1. Do not create Project Folder Manually , it will automatically get created via `npx create-react-app`

Answer (score 0):

To answer to your own explanation of your problem.
Personally, I used `npx create-next-app@latest` ([Next](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/installation)) so my project was create automatically but I had the same error : `npm ERR! enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory`
If I've understood correctly, you need to run your command `npm start` (or `npm run dev` with next) in the folder **where the package.json** file is located.